# Bugzilla: Software error: Cannot determine local time zone

Tags: bugzilla

I just finished installing BugZilla however I am not being prompted to setup and admin account. The database indicates there is a user created with the email `admin@mydomain.com` so I am trying to reset the password. When I try to reset the password I get the following error:

> Software error:
>
> Cannot determine local time zone

The timezone is set:

```
$ dpkg-reconfigure tzdata

Current default time zone: 'America/New_York'
Local time is now:      Tue Oct 14 21:14:12 EDT 2014.
Universal Time is now:  Wed Oct 15 01:14:12 UTC 2014.
```

I cannot follow instructions like [these](http://mozilla.6506.n7.nabble.com/undef-error-Cannot-determine-local-time-zone-td71278.html) as I do not have access to the admin panel as of yet, as I don't have access because of not having an admin account. What should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just did a `sudo cpan DateTime::TimeZone` and that fixed the issue.

Comment: s/cpam/cpan/ but otherwise what he said.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error with perl on Windows which was fixed by installing the module DateTime::TimeZone::Local::Win32

Comment: thanks, on ActivePerl it could also be `ppm install DateTime::TimeZone::Local::Win32`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. 
I resolved it by putting BEGIN { $ENV{TZ} = 'America/Denver' } in the Bugzilla/Util.pm file. 
See  code snippet below & insert " BEGIN { $ENV{TZ} = 'America/Denver' } " as shown

```
`use Date::Parse; 
use Date::Format; 
BEGIN { $ENV{TZ} = 'America/Denver' } 
use DateTime; 
use DateTime::TimeZone; `
```

I hope this helps. -

Answer (score 0):

Same problem.  I eventually tracked this down to an old version of `List::Util` in the Bugzilla lib after I updated Bugzilla. I fixed this by using :

```
$ ./install-module.pl List::Util
```